# How to update secrets using Ssm parameter store using terraform while creating resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-ssm

I’m using terraform to spin up ECS service using some secrets by creating parameters in SSM parameter store. The problem is I cannot have the secrets in my terraform config files so i am creating those parameters using default values first using terraform apply -target=aws_ssm_parameter.example and then i am manually updating the secrets in Aws console then doing terraform apply on all the resources which will pick the new parameter values but is there any workaround for this to keep it simple and do it in one go with terraform apply without using target. I tried very hard to find but couldn’t get possible solution.

Here is my Tf code for ssm parameter where i am just passing default value and then changing it in AWS console before applying terraform for whole resources.

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "example" {
  name  = "/${terraform.workspace}/${local.app}/username"
  type  = "SecureString"
  value = "default"

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [value]
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that with your current method your secrets will still get written in plain text to your statefile, so ensure that's encrypted and secure. IMO there is no benefit to what you are doing now vs fully manually managing the secrets outside of TF. [SOPS](https://github.com/mozilla/sops) is a tool some use to maintain secrets alongside TF code.

Comment: You can use [terraform vault](https://www.hashicorp.com/resources/managing-vault-with-terraform) to store credentials. This way you can just decrypt the vault and run terraform apply.

Comment: Best practices for this would be to pass the secrets as inputs to Terraform via env variables. With that you would achieve everything you listed in the question.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Let me try is this the only way like shown below or any other ways. export TF_VAR_region=us-west-1 export TF_VAR_ami=ami-049d8641

Comment: @GeorgePaul Yes now simply broker those from your secrets management retrieval in an ephemeral instance, such as in a container in a pipeline.

Comment: @MattSchuchard yeah let me see that. Do you have any reference where I can follow.